# Мультиязычность на сайте

Tags: php

Скажите, как реализована мультиязычность на **Facebook** или в **VK**? Нужно сделать мультиязычность средствами **php**.

Comment: Выносим все строки, которые нужно перевести, в отдельный файлик с переводами, в зависимости от выбранного пользователя языка загружаем файлик с нужным языком и печатаем строки из этого файлика, всё просто

Comment: @andreymal, а подойдут константы? Например, define('TITLE', 'WELCOME').

Comment: константы - это костыльный вариант. Потому что нет возможности манипулировать нашими строками. Поэтому обычно используют именно файлы, не один файл а файлы, на каждый шаблон - свой файл.

Comment: константы только в переопределении данных. Константы не предполагают change/update - а это иногда нужно

Comment: В пыхе для этого есть [gettext](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.gettext.php). Просто создай mo-файл с переводом и выстави нужную локаль.

Answer (score 0):

Попробую внести ясность и свое мнение:

**Предисловие:**

Начать надо с определения языка. Обычно делаю через куки (либо привязывают к аккаунту если есть авторизация).

Предположим, что кука будет называться `lang`, Тогда в скрипте смотрим: если такой куки нет, то язык - стандартный (который мы укажем в качестве стандартного), если существует: то смотрим значение этой куки, если такой язык существует в нашем пуле, то значит значение валидно язык известен, иначе опять стандартную.

С определением языка - определились. Идем дальше: на беке обычно реализуют одним из следующих способов:

**1) Языковые файлы**

Т.е. у нас есть директория `language` в которой есть языковые папки а в них файлы с текстами:

```
language
-english
--tpl_1.php
--tpl_2.php
-russian
--tpl_1.php
--tpl_2.php
```

Идея в том, что каждый файл содержит в себе массив `[key1 => value1, key2 => value2]`, Где `value` - Наш текст, а `key` - уникальный идентификатор, по которому мы и будем запрашивать наш локализованный конкретный текст. (ну думаю логика понятна).

Почему я написал `tpl_` - ? Потому что архитектурно правильней текст формировать на последнем этапе (`views`), т.е. контроллер - только собирает необходимые данные.

В общем случае схема такая: контроллер знает какие вьюхи он подргрузит, поэтому подгружает сперва массивы языковых файлов (наши `tpl_`), потом эти массивы передает в `views` там они уще шаблонизатором вставляются - *profit!*

В процессе прочтения вы небось подумали что лажа какая-то, соглашусь. Поэтому такой подход чаще всего используется когда нам ВСЕ ТАКИ НАДО чтобы в контроллере к нашим данным прикрепить какие-то языковые строки.

**2) Шаблонный**

Зачем контроллеру передавать массивы с шаблонами и так заморачиваться, если просто можно создать 2 одинаковых шаблона с разными языками? Гениально!

**2+1) Шаблонно-файловый**

Собсна 2 способ не менее костыльный, чем первый, потому что вам придется поддерживать 2 шаблона, т.е. любую правку дублировать и т.д. Морока. Дайте проще!

Поэтому самый правильный способ: совместить. Т.е. каждый шаблон будет содержать в себе функцию для получения языкового текста, пример:

Пусть у нас есть шаблон `tpl_home`:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>{% lang('tpl_home.title') %}</title>
</head>
<body>
{% lang('tpl_home.body') %}
</body>
</html>
```

Задача нашего шаблонизатора: Найти все наши `{% lang(...) %}` и заменить их на текст.

Например `{% lang('tpl_home.title') %}` , тут `tpl_home` - это файл с шаблоном,
`title` - ключ самого массива внутри файла.

Значит получается, что мы запрашиваем `language/russian/tpl_home.php` получаем от туда наш массив (пусть будет например `$array`), и теперь заменяем `{% lang('tpl_home.title') %}` в шаблоне на значение `$array['title']`. (Откуда взяли `russian`? Ну язык мы определили в предисловии)

---

**P.S.** Вообще правильная и гибкая логика очень сложная. У вас должна быть отдельная логика `Локализации` и отдельная логика `Шаблонизатора` и при этом они должны взаимодействовать между собой и понимать друг друга. Так просто описать не получится, но в целом описал, как толчок - самое-то. Либо используйте фреймворки, там уже это все есть :)

**P.S.2.** Тут мы уже коснулись темы шаблонизатора, что в свою очередь - является еще целой горой проблем. И при нагруженных проектах, шаблонизатор должен уметь грамотно кешировать такие файлы. Но это отдельная история... Лукас если дочитал.